# Is conjugate of holomorphic function holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is holomorphic, does it follow that $g(z)=\overline{f(z)}$ is holomorphic?

I'm looking at $$\lim_{z\rightarrow a}\dfrac{g(z)-g(a)}{z-a} = \lim_{z\rightarrow a}\dfrac{\overline{f(z)-f(a)}}{z-a}$$

Can we pull the limit out to get $\overline{\lim_{z\rightarrow a}\dfrac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}}$?

Comment: $f(z) = z$ is holomorphic, but $\overline{f(z)} = \overline{z}$ is not.

Comment: Note that if you tried to pull the complex conjugate out of the limit, you would have to conjugate the denominator.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes, good point. I forgot that.

Comment: But $$g(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$$ is holomorphic (on the reflection of the domain of $f$).

Comment: @DanielFischer, why is that?

Comment: @Ian Because one conjugates twice. The composition of a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map with an antilinear map is antilinear, the composition of two antilinear maps is linear. In the same way (and for the same reason), the composition of a holomorphic and an antiholomorphic map is antiholomorphic, and the composition of two antiholomorphic maps is holomorphic. Conjugation is antiholomorphic, so the composition of holomorphic maps with an even number of conjugations, in whatever order, is holomorphic; with an odd number of conjugations, antiholomorphic.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3713822/532409

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. When you took the conjugation out, it forces you to conjugate $z-a$ in the denominator.

An easy (and canonical) way to see that the conjugate of a holomorphic function is not holomorphic is to consider $z\mapsto \overline z$. This is easily confirmed by looking at the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 14):

If $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ then $\overline{f(z)}=u(x,y)-iv(x,y)$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations imply $v=\operatorname{const}$. Hence $u(x,y)=\operatorname{const}$

Comment: By Cauchy - Riemann we get $v_x=v_y$ and $u_x=u_y$, which is the result or the fact to conclude that $u$ and $v$ are constant?

Comment: $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$ from f holomorphic

Comment: $u_x = -v_y$ and $u_y = v_x$ from conjugate holomorphic so they are all $0$