# If $f$ is an entire function then is $f(\bar{z})$ is also entire?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is an entire function then is $f(\bar{z})$ is also entire?

I'm thinking about it a lot and I think changing the variable from $z$ to $\bar{z}$ doesn't change anything because it's already analytic on every point of $\mathbb{C}$.

AmI correct?

Comment: is $\bar{z}$ entire?

Comment: @SeanNemetz sorry?

Comment: Just consider $f$ the identity.

Comment: is the function $f(\bar{z})=\bar{z}$ analytic everywhere on the complex plane? $z$ is definitely entire, however...

Comment: @SeanNemetz can you please elaborate that why $\bar{z}$ is not analytic everywhere?

Comment: Use Cauchy-Riemann and the chain rule for Wirtinger derivatives: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}f(\bar z)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(\bar z)\frac{\partial \bar z}{\partial \bar z}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}(\bar z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial \bar z}=f'(\bar z)$$ Therefore given $f$ holomorphic on some open set, $f(\bar z)$ is holomorphic if and only if $f$ is locally constant on its domain.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1138819/42969

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you but I'm afraid I don't understand this because I don't know "Wirtinger derivative" yet.

Comment: @Itachi Ok, I'll keep in mind not to delete the comment, then.

Comment: @Itachi  You are probably missing a bar.$\overline{f(\overline{z})} $

Comment: Differentiation free approach: assume WLOG $f(0)=0$.  If $f(\bar z)$ is analytic then $f(z)=f(\bar z)$ (why?). Consider closed disc $\overline B(0,r)$ with $r$ small enough so $f$ is non-zero on the punctured disc $\overline B^*(0,r)$. Let closed curve $\gamma:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ be given by $\gamma(t)=r\cdot \exp(2 \pi i \cdot t)$. Then for $t\in [\frac{1}{2},1]$ we have $f\circ \gamma(t) = f\circ \gamma(1-t) $ i.e. it is the reversal of $f\circ \gamma(t)$ for $t\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$.  This contradicts Argument Principle for a disc. (This can be made rigorous with winding numbers.)