$\overline{f}$ and $f^3$ are holomorphic on $\mathbb C$
Context: Let $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$, such that its conjugate $\overline{f}$ and its cube $f^3$ are both entire functions.
Or even more generally, under some conditions, does there exist a way to obtain an entire function from a non entire function composed with polynomial one?
Question: How could I prove that $f$ must be constant?
So far:

I tried by using Cauchy-Riemann equations but I got to anywhere. For example:
Let be $f=U+iV$,  $f^2=U^∗+iV^∗$ where $U^∗=2UU_x−2VV_x$ and $V^∗=2U_yV+2UV_y$. This leads to $U(U_x−V_y)=V(V_x+U_y)$ and there isn't a clear path where I can use the hypothesis. If $f^3$ instead $f^2$, the final equation is even worse.
Another path I tried: If $f$ is not an entire function and if I supposed that $f$ is not constant, then there exists a point $z_0$
such that $\lim_{z→z_0}(f(z))^3$ does not exist, and at this point I missed something.


Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Maybe the answers to this topic are useful for you: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/515876/226969

Post your efforts, not only tell us about them. What did you get when you tried using the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Of course. Sorry if I didn't do that before, I'm getting use to this site.  Let be $f(z)=U(x,y) + iV(x,y)$, then for example, $f^2 (z)= U^* (x,y) + iV^(x,y)$ where $U^ = 2UU_x - 2VV_x$ and $V^*=2U_yV + 2UV_y$ This leads to $U(U_x - V_y))=V(V_x + U_y)$ and this tell me nothing usefull (aparently)

Another path I tried: If f is not an entire function and if I suposed that is not constant, then exist a point $z_o$ where there is not exist the limit of $\Lim_{z\to z_o}$ $f^3 (z)=\Lim_{z\to z_o}f(z)*f(z)*f(z)$ and and at this point I missed something

Sorry, I intended to vote to reopen and my finger slipped!

Since $\bar{f}$ is entire, so is $\bar{g}$, where $g := f^3$ is entire. Hence $\mathrm{Re}(g) = (g + \bar{g}) /2$ is entire. But the image of $\mathrm{Re}(g)$ is contained in the real line, thus by Picard's little theorem, $\mathrm{Re}(g)$ is constant.
Similarly $\mathrm{Im}(g) = (g - \bar{g}) /(2i) $ is a real-value entire function and hence also constant.
Therefore $g = \mathrm{Re}(g) + i\mathrm{Im}(g)$ is constant. Since $f^3 = g$, therefore the image of $f$ is a set with at most 3 points. Therefore, by Picard's little theorem again, $f$ is constant.
